# OpenVR (missing from build)

Tags: unity-game-engine, openvr

I set up a clean project and import steamVR from Asset Store:

[image: Asset Store]

I chose to Import All

[image: Import all]

In player Setting OpenVR doesn't even show up in my list of supported virtual reality. Instead it shows that it's "missing from build".

[image: Virtual reality SDKs]

On the build I get an error :

```
DllNotFoundException: openvr_api
Valve.VR.OpenVR.GetInitToken () (at Assets/SteamVR/Plugins/openvr_api.cs:4195)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT : Add step of the import as requested.

Comment: Please list the exact steps you did to perform the import. If you can use the "Steps Recorder" tool built in to windows to get screenshots of each click.

Comment: Just edited the question with screenshots. btw I'm developing on Mac El Capitan, but making windows builds. Thx

Answer (score 0):

I not exactly know what happened, but I can give you some steps to check that:

1. make sure you installed Steam and then installed SteamVR
2. running SteamVR and sure this app works normally using your HMD like HTC Vive
3. check you Unity3D edition does support VR, and a latest one prefer.

I think the `DllNotFoundException` in your case caused by SteamVR installed incorrectly.